# Invalid Template in kendo dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, kendo-ui

i want to display template if data value == "Low". So i created template column like following

```
template: '# if( data=="Low" ){#<span><i class="fa fa-square blue"></i> <span># } '
```

but it displays error like

> Error: Invalid template:'# if( data=="Low" ){# # } #: data #' Generated code:'var $kendoOutput, $kendoHtmlEncode = kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){$kendoOutput=''; if( data=="Low" ){;$kendoOutput+=' '; } ;$kendoOutput+=': data ';;$kendoOutput+=;}return $kendoOutput;'

please help me. i am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to end template with #, it should be like below.

```
template: '# if( data=="Low" ){#<span><i class="fa fa-square blue"></i> <span># } #'
```